# Can structs be cast to a different size in the following way?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, exception, mfc, struct

OS: Windows x86, MFC, CRT, VS2010

I'm running into a run-time CRT heap corruption exception after upgrading from Visual Studio 2005 (SP1) to VS2010-SP1.

The CRT only complains about the corruption when my app is compiled with debug. And I believe that VS2010 is just too strict when it is evaluating memory accesses.

The suspected offending code does the following:

```
typedef struct _T_TEST
{
    DWORD flag;
    TCHAR str[1];
} T_TEST;

// Then the structure is used in this way
void test(TCHAR * p_str) {
    DWORD size = sizeof(DWORD) + (_tcslen(p_str) + 1) * sizeof(TCHAR);
    T_TEST * foo = (T_TEST *) calloc(size, 1);
    foo->flag = 0;
    _tcscpy_s(foo->str, size - sizeof(DWORD), p_str);
    // Do IPC with the struct
    // When finished, free it
    free(foo);
}
```

This code sometimes fails on `free(foo)` and other times when casting the allocated buffer to `(T_TEST *)`.

Is extending the struct size in that way valid? And is there something different in VS2010 that treats that as a heap corruption?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Mark Ransom pointed out your bug.  I just want to comment that if visual studio says your heap is corrupt, it is telling you the truth and trying to help you.  Please do not argue with it!  Spend your effort looking for your bugs not trying to justify marginal code.

Comment: Also your question is flagged as C++, but you are using C techniques (calloc and free rather than new and delete)  Modern C++ is much safer than C and if you used it correctly you would be much less likely to encounter this type of error.

Comment: Noted. How do you remove a tag? (never mind)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter to `_tcscpy_s` is the number of elements but you're feeding it the number of bytes. According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The debug versions of these functions first fill the buffer with 0xFE.

This will result in a buffer overflow if sizeof(TCHAR) != 1.

Comment: Urrr! You must think that I'm colossal idiot. I'm converting a large project to use Unicode and there are thousands of these little mistakes. Thanks for the help. But I'm still curious if this dynamic size increase is acceptable.

Comment: @rbhkamal, I never judge - we all have bad days and miss the simple stuff. C and C++ don't really have any good facilities for dynamic sized structures, so this is probably the best you can do. I don't see any obvious problems. The only thing I'd change is to use `new char[size]` instead of `calloc`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with the code that could cause heap corruption: Passing the size in bytes instead of the character count to `_tcscpy_s` and calculating the wrong buffer size.

A correct implementation should look roughly like this:

```
void test(TCHAR * p_str) {
    // Calculate the input string length
    size_t len = _tcslen(p_str);

    // Calculate the buffer size  (1)
    size_t bufferSize = offsetof(T_TEST, str[len + 1]);

    // Allocate a buffer
    vector<char> buffer(bufferSize);

    // Map the structure onto the buffer to get a T_TEST*
    T_TEST* foo = reinterpret_cast<T_TEST*>(&buffer[0]);

    foo->flag = 0;
    // This potentially writes beyond the end  (2)
    //_tcscpy_s(foo->str, size - sizeof(DWORD), p_str);
    _tcscpy(foo->str, len + 1, p_str);

    // Do IPC with the struct
    // When finished, free it

    // buffer will be automatically cleaned up
    //free(foo);
}
```

(1) The size of a structure is not necessarily the same as the sum of the sizes of its members. Depending on the target platform and/or compiler settings the compiler will align the individual members to meet the alignment requirements. To do so it (potentially) adds padding between them. Using [`offsetof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz4y9b9a.aspx) is a convenient way to have the compiler do the calculations.

(2) In the original code there are 2 issues: The call to [`_tcscpy_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td1esda9.aspx) requires the size of the destination buffer in number of characters, not the size in bytes. There is also a hidden gotcha: The expression `foo->str` instructs the compiler to calculate the offset, taking potential padding into account. The expression `size - sizeof(DWORD)` however does not account for padding, which opens the possibility to write beyond the end of the allocated buffer.

Since you are dealing with an MFC application I assume that using C++ is ok, even though the question is not tagged `C++`. If you cannot or do not want to use `std::vector` you can allocate the buffer using `new char[bufferSize]` and `delete[] buffer;` to clean up.